# Skipping rows in numpy ndarrays slicing

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a numpy array `img`, with `img.shape == (468,832,3)`. What does `img[::2, ::2]` do? It reduces the shape to `(234,416,3)` Can you please explain the logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's read documentation together [(Source).](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
 (Just read the bold part first)

> The basic slice syntax is **i:j:k** where **i** is the **starting index**, **j** is the **stopping index**, and **k** is the **step** (k \neq 0). This selects the m elements (in the corresponding dimension) with index values i, i + **k**, ..., i + (m - 1) **k** where m = q + (r\neq0) and q and r are the quotient and remainder obtained by dividing j - i by k: j - i = q k + r, so that i + (m - 1) k < j.
>
> ...
>
> Assume **n** is the number of elements in the dimension being sliced.
>   Then, **if i is not given it defaults to 0 for k > 0** and n - 1 for k < 0
>   . **If j is not given it defaults to n for k > 0** and -n-1 for k < 0 . If
>   k is not given it defaults to 1. Note that :: is the same as : and
>   means select all indices along this axis.

Now looking at your part.

`[::2, ::2]` will be translated to `[0:468:2, 0:832:2]` because you do not specify the first two or `i` and `j` in the documentation. (You only specify `k` here. Recall the `i:j:k` notation above.) You select elements on these axes at the step size 2 which means you select every other elements along the axes specified.

Because you did not specify for the 3rd dimension, all will be selected.

Comment: Thanks! The last line solved my problem. I was confused about there not being a 3rd index for a 3d array.

Comment: @VaishnavMK no problem :P

Comment: I understand why you feel like that. Sorry if it felt really silly. But I basically started using numpy and 3d arrays slicing yesterday and was totally lost with advanced slicing vs basic slicing, so I hadn't really started playing much yet, just exploring basic concepts by asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

It slices every alternate row, and then every alternate column, from an array, returning an array of size `(n // 2, n // 2, ...)`.

Here's an example of slicing with a 2D array -

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

```
>>> a[::2, ::2]
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

And, here's another example with a 3D array -

```
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

```
>>> a[::2, ::2] # same as a[::2, ::2, :]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: Can u please explain how `[: : 2, : : 2]` slices alternate rows and columns of a 3d array language (in noob language)?

Comment: @VaishnavMK It should be clearer with another example. It's not something you explain, but understand. You are specifying the "axes" along which you slice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have the RGB image as a 3D array of shape:

```
img.shape=(468,832,3)
```

Now, what does `img[::2, ::2]` do?

we're just **downsampling the image** (i.e. we're shrinking the image size by half by taking *only* every other pixel from the original image and we do this by using a step size of `2`, which means to skip one pixel). This should be clear from the example below.

Let's take a simple *grayscale* image for easier understanding.

```
In [13]: arr
Out[13]: 
array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]])

In [14]: arr.shape
Out[14]: (6, 6)

In [15]: arr[::2, ::2]
Out[15]: 
array([[10, 12, 14],
       [30, 32, 34],
       [50, 52, 54]])

In [16]: arr[::2, ::2].shape
Out[16]: (3, 3)
```

Notice which *pixels* are in the sliced version. Also, observe how the array `shape` changes after slicing (i.e. it is reduced by half).

Now, this downsampling happens for all three channels in the image since there's no slicing happening in the third axis. Thus, you will get the shape reduced only for the first two axis in your example.

```
(468, 832, 3)
  .    .   |
  .    .   |
(234, 416, 3)
```